# How to create the map Of the vector of structure in c++

Tags: c++, struct, stdvector, stdmap

I have a map `std::map<int, std::vector<Data>>myMap` and my structure is defined as follows.

```
        struct Data
        {
         int x;
         int z;
         int y;
        };
```

in myMap key is int and value is vector of structure and I dont want create the temporary vector or structure while inserting to the map. Is there any idea to achieve it?

Comment: `myMap[123]` returns a reference to the vector at that key (creating it if it doesn't exist), so `myMap[123].push_back({x,y,z});` should add `{x,y,z}` to the newly created / existing vector without using a temporary vector.  Something like https://onlinegdb.com/HJgoqrElkw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly initilize values in a map. When you access a key via [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) that does not exist in the map it will be added with a default initialized value (an empty `std::vector` in your case).

So you can safely do something like

```
myMap[0].push_back(myInstanceOfData)
```

even if the key 0 does not exist. Then it will be created along with an empty vector as value and the value `myInstanceOfData` will be pushed to this new vector inside the map.

Comment: I don't want to create extra object of the vector.I want to directly insert to the map without having any object of the vector  .better by using initialization list

Comment: You don't create an extra object here. You only have the object that is stored in the map. _"directly insert to the map without having any object of the vector"_ - sorry, not sure what you mean here, you have a map with `std::vector` as value, you will _always_ have `std::vector` stored in the map, because that's how you declared it.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `emplace` and `std::move`

```
myMap.emplace(key, std::move(myVec));
```

By using `std::move` you can construct the vector outside of the map, and then move that vector into the map without any copying.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer said, you can use emplace and std::move, but to test if it or any other solution works, I suggest you override the constructor, copy constructor, destructor, and the assignment operator to print something like created, copied, destroyed, assigned respectively, so you know what's actually going on, and improve performance.